# How to use the vectorize numpy function in python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I tried in ipython following code: I want to use vectorize and give the function prox(x,tau). But the first value in lambda comes always two times.

```
In [32]: a = np.array([[ 1., 2.],[ 3., 4.]])
In [33]: def prox(x, tau):
    ...:     print x, tau
    ...:     if x >= tau:
    ...:         print "first"
    ...:         return x-tau
    ...:     if -tau <= x and x <= tau:
    ...:         print "second"
    ...:         return 0.0
    ...:     if x <= -tau:
    ...:         print "third"
    ...:         return x+tau

In [34]: b = np.vectorize(lambda x: prox(x, 2))(a[:,1:])
In [35]: b 
2.0 2
first
2.0 2
first
4.0 2
first
```

Why in line 35 is two times printed the same value? 2.0 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify `otypes`, then `vectorize` performs a test calculation with the first value, and uses that to determine the `dtype` of the array it returns.  Hence the double evaluation of the first item.

Usually that extra calculation is unimportant.  But be careful.  If that initial calculation returns an integer (e.g. scalar 0) the returned array will also be integer, loosing any float values in subsequent calculations.

For more details review the docs for `vectorize`.

[vectorize is indeterminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433587/vectorize-is-indeterminate) - An error produced by an unintended integer otype.  I've seen this error in other SO questions.